# Вызов const версии метода

Tags: const, классы, c++

Доброго времени суток.
Допустим, у класса есть два перегруженных метода, различающихся только наличием `const` после сигнатуры. Вопрос: как у неконстантного объекта этого класса вызвать константную перегрузку этого метода без создания временного объекта (так как при кастах он создается)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](http://ideone.com/0GvnZZ):

```
auto const& const_instance = instance;
const_instance.method();
```

Здесь по идее копирования не будет.

Ещё один путь:

```
static_cast<const YourClass*>(&instance)->method();
```

Comment: Спасибо, но как быть, если объект - временный, и у него нельзя взять адрес или сделать const ссылку на него ввиду того, что он rvalue и все равно будет создана копия? Пока на ум приходит лишь "обходной путь" - создать у класса метод, который возвращает ссылку на себя, вызвать его, результат (который уже lvalue) привести к const одним из методов, о которых вы уже сказали и затем уже непосредственно вызвать сам метод. Но можно ли это сделать как-то более корректно? А то что-то не красиво как-то получается )

Comment: Хм. `static_cast` по идее не должен делать копий. Можете привести пример кода, когда рецепт из ответа не сработает?

Comment: Я имел ввиду, например, такой случай
https://ideone.com/CVRgGI
Но так как компилятор оптимизирует инициализацию, то действительно, никакие копии не создаются (но по стандарту, насколько я знаю, вовсе не гарантируется наличие такой оптимизации)

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с С++17 можно воспользоваться стандартным псевдокастом `as_const`.

```
::std::as_const(object).method();
```